# reading int16 data in matlab

Tags: matlab, hex, signed

I read this set of hex values from an accelerometer datalogging:

> 35AC,2889,1899,0C4A,058B,FD46,F620,F001,EE44,EF08,EF46,F750,007F,0814,1369,21F3,34F0,45CE,5992,6D05,7C12,7FEF,7FF8,7FF8,7FF8,7FF8,7FD9,7F27,74A7,67D8,5826,468F,3621,2573,1326,0441,F88F,F1BF,F082,EADB,EAEE,EE04,F190,F89E,01F5,0B0C,155A,2721,3A20,48DC,5985,676A,721E,7C20,7FF8,7FEE,7F1B,

It should somehow draw a sinusoide curve, but I could not find the right import method for signed `int16` and the curve jumps from 0 to 65535.

Could you please help me?

I have tried `sscanf(...,'%4x')`

Answer (score 0):

The `sscanf` format for a signed hex int16 is just `'%4i'`. Unfortunately it expects that hex values will begin with `0x`, which yours clearly don't. One possibility is for you to scan it in as you are, and then manually convert it to a signed int16. One possible way of doing this would be the following:

```
input = sscanf(...,'%4x');
input16 = typecast(uint16(input),'int16');
```

The values are being read in as a uint32 and automatically converted to double by the `sscanf` function. So we convert it to a uint16, then typecast it to a 16-bit int (note that just using `int16(input)` doesn't work, as it doesn't convert values over INT16_MAX to negative values).

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '35AC,2889,1899,0C4A,058B,FD46,F620,F001,EE44,EF08,EF46,F750,007F,0814,1369,21F3,34F0,45CE,5992,6D05,7C12,7FEF,7FF8,7FF8,7FF8,7FF8,7FD9,7F27,74A7,67D8,5826,468F,3621,2573,1326,0441,F88F,F1BF,F082,EADB,EAEE,EE04,F190,F89E,01F5,0B0C,155A,2721,3A20,48DC,5985,676A,721E,7C20,7FF8,7FEE,7F1B';
%// Your data as a string

string = [string ',']; %// add ending comma to reshape into groups of five chars
strings = reshape(string,5,[]).';
strings = strings(:,1:4); %'// each row is 4 chars representing a hex number
numbers = hex2dec(strings); %// convert each row to a number
ind = numbers>=32768;
numbers(ind) = numbers(ind)-65535;  %// get rid of jumps
plot(numbers)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thank a lot

Both previous answer were [there](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46275-how-can-i-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-from-two-s-complement-to-a-signed-int) too.

sscanf alternative assumed to be faster.